# How to add transition from one function to another in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add some smooth transition or animation from the mouse enter event to the mouse leave.

**JS :**

```js
/* mudar cor do logo maior */
var myImage = document.querySelector('img#logo-maior');

myImage.onmouseenter = function() {
    var mySrc = myImage.getAttribute('src');
    myImage.setAttribute ('src','images/type-logo-coral.png');   
}

myImage.onmouseleave = function() {
    var mySrc = myImage.getAttribute('src');
    myImage.setAttribute ('src','images/type-logo.png');
}
```

**HTML :**

```html
<div class="display">
    <img id="modelos" src="images/modelos/1.png">
    <img id="logo-maior" src="images/type-logo.png" alt="TYPE logo">
<!-- 
<button type="button" onclick="displayPreviousImage()">Previous</button>
<button type="button" onclick="displayNextImage()">Next</button>
-->
</div>
```

Comment: you want to transition the image?

Comment: Can you edit your post and explain what is your goal here? What do you want to apply the transition to and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS Animation. Add class for each function that will trigger the animation

Try this code

css

```
.transition1{
  animation: fadeIn1 1.5s; 
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn1 1.5s;  ;
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes fadeIn1{
 from{
 opacity: 0;
}
 to{
  opacity: 1;
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframeskeyframes fadeIn1{
 from{
   opacity: 0;
 }
 to{
   opacity: 1;
 }
}

 .transition2{
   animation: fadeIn2 1.5s; 
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn2 1.5s; ;
   opacity: 1;
 }

 @-webkit-keyframeskeyframes fadeIn2{
   from{
     opacity: 0;
    }
  to{
    opacity: 1;
  }
 }
```

javascript

```
var myImage = document.querySelector("img#logo-maior");

myImage.onmouseenter = function() {
    myImage.classList.remove("transition2");
    myImage.setAttribute("class", "transition1");

  myImage.setAttribute("src", "../image2.jpg");
};

myImage.onmouseleave = function() {
    myImage.classList.remove("transition1");
    myImage.setAttribute("class", "transition2");

  myImage.setAttribute("src","../image1.jpg"
 );
};
```

html

```
 <div class="display">
     <img
        id="logo-maior"
        src="../img1.jpg"
        alt="TYPE logo"
      />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS code:

```
img:hover {
(whatever styles you want for the hovering effect)
transition: all 0.5s ease-out; 
}
```

For more information on transitions visit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Comment: You're going to have to put more effort into this answer. `transition` only works on CSS styles, not the `<img>` `src` attribute like what the asker is using. Additionally, not all CSS styles support transitions; for example, `background-image` doesn't support transitions.

Comment: @Ouroborus - Actually, background-image **DOES** support transitions - just not in every browser apparently

Comment: That was my mistake, didn't read that he was changing src with it, I only read "looking to make effect by hovering over"

Comment: I guess you're technically right (the best kind of right) regarding `background-image`. I'm not sure how useful it is in practice, though, given that the effect is discrete, no cross-fade or whatever without help.